# What is the most efficient way of outputting strings stored in a stack but with the letters of the strings reversed in order?

Tags: c++, stack

What the program does is allows the user to input a bunch of strings, stores them in a stack, and then outputs all of those strings in the stack but in reverse order and flipped. Is there a more efficient way of doing what I did? Maybe using a different data structure (other than a stack)? I though a stack would be best because the strings stored in the stacks need to be outputted in the opposite order that they were inputted.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack <string> elements;
    string element;

    cout << "Hello, welcome to Flippy-McBackwardson! \n\n" << endl;

    cout << "Please enter a bunch of strings (type END to terminate your list): " << endl;

    do {
        getline(cin, element);

        elements.push(element);
    } while (element != "END");

    elements.pop();

    cout << "\nFlippy Backward Version: " << endl;

    for (int x = elements.size()-1; x >= 0; x--){
        for (int i = elements.top().length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            cout << elements.top()[i];
        }
        elements.pop();
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably should be a `std::reverse` in there somewhere.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `stack` rather than a `vector`?

Comment: What makes you worried about the efficiency of this code ?

Comment: @SidS I am worried about efficiency because I am getting graded on efficiency in this computer science course that I am taking, so I just needed help with that. I am sure that the way I did it is reasonably efficient, but I just wanted to see if there are more efficient ways of solving this problem and why. That's all. Just had a question to ask and wanted to learn. I don't know why my question got down voted. By the way, this isn't my homework, I just thought of this and wanted to see if there are more efficient ways of solving it

Comment: @Zaid, In that case I would show this code to your professor or TA and ask them how it would be graded and whether it's necessary to improve it, and if so - how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *reverse iterators* (accessible using `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()`) which should be cleaner and safer as they don't involve tricky subscripting math that is prone to *off-by-one* errors (at the very least).

```
while(!elements.empty())
{
    std::for_each(std::rbegin(elements.top()), std::rend(elements.top()),
        [](char c){ std::cout << c; });

    std::cout << '\n';

    elements.pop();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are iterators?

Comment: @Galik, While this is good advice, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @SidS I suppose I could argue that there are different kinds of "efficiency" to be considered. :)